# Target an element not knowing its ID (Sceditor - forumotion forum)

Tags: javascript, forum

I am not strong knowledge in JavaScript.

We have a Tamil language forum got from forumotion.com.
Forumotion now upgraded old editor to new Sceditor for all forums.

Old editor textarea has id attribute, so that we had using Google tamil idic web version, but in Sceditor, the textarea has no such id attribute, so that we can't type in Tamil language.

How to assign id attribute to that textarea?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the DOM structure is always the same, you could eventually use jQuery for that and target the element yourself. For example, you know there is a `div class="sceditor-toolbar"` and an `iframe` preceding your textarea so your selector would look like
`$('div.sceditor-toolbar + iframe + textarea')`

To add `id` to mentioned element, you can use
`$('div.sceditor-toolbar + iframe + textarea').attr("id","value");`

jQuery uses css syntax for matching elements, read more at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).